# Display only one component with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

i'm creating a simple movie app with React along with the movie rest api from TMDB. My Home page is welcoming the users showing the most popular movies trending nowadays. Now i would like to insert on the navbar a link to open another page that will show all the categories. I'm new to React Router so i might have doing it wrong, but when i try to redirect to the "category" component, the component will show on the same page without hiding the home page. That's the code:

```
   <Router>
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <SearchAppBar handleChange={handleChange} query={query} />
        <TitlebarGridList movies={movies} />
        <Typography
          component="div"
          style={{ backgroundColor: "white", height: "100vh" }}
        />
      </Container>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/categories">
          <Category />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```

If i type on the browser /category, the category component will showe behind the App homepage. How can i show only that one i want?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try also to wrap the container with a route having `/` as path :

```
  <Router>
    <Switch>
     <Route exact path="/">
      <Container maxWidth="xl">
        <SearchAppBar handleChange={handleChange} query={query} />
        <TitlebarGridList movies={movies} />
        <Typography
          component="div"
          style={{ backgroundColor: "white", height: "100vh" }}
        />
      </Container>
       </Route>
        <Route exact path="/categories">
          <Category />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
```